# API - Unique identifier per status update?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm investigating using the DocuSign API to send & receive envelopes and signed documents.

Does DocuSign provide an 'event ID' or something that's unique to each status update of an envelope? I want to know if we've processed this event already or not.

**My question is**, Is there any way to easily identify what has changed in the status update that we receive from DocuSign?

Or an appropriate way to translate the WebAPI calls to the SDK objects & methods?

Comment: your question is not clear. are you asking about the "Connect" web hook that calls your web application to update you about status changes for DocuSign envelopes?

Comment: Hi Inbar, yes- when using Connect, with the web-hook to 'listen' for updates, does DocuSign provide a unique ID per update? 

When I receive an update, as the consumer, will it be clear to me what the update is? For example, John Smith signed envelope 123456.... or will I have to compare field by field?

Comment: yes, we provide the EnvelopeID which is a GUID and unique per envelope. However, the same envelope may be updated multiple times, that's why you also get a status update with the specific status that the envelope is at.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. Is there any documentation on what the status the envelopes could be in, and sample updates? We are using the C# SDK to send the DocuSign updates, and will also be using a C# Connect listener .

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-status has all the possible statuses

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick which can be applied to know what has changed in the envelope without parsing the complete XML. If you have your Rest Listener as `https://www.acme.com/connect`, then you can add another query parameter to your connect URL, and your URL should be like

- `https://www.acme.com/connect?event=envelopeDecline`
- `https://www.acme.com/connect?event=envelopeComplete` etc..

Then create multiple Connect Configuration is your DS Account, by mapping correct trigger events to correct Rest listener URL.

Like `https://www.acme.com/connect?event=envelopeComplete` should be configured with only Envelope Signed/Completed envelope-level trigger event.

simlarly `https://www.acme.com/connect?event=envelopeDecline` should be configured with only Envelope Declined envelope=level trigger event.

By doing this way, your listener has to just read the query params first which will tell you what type of XML or status of envelope is sent in the XML, and then direct your code to correct processing method for further parsing of the XML. By following this trick, this will tell your listener what has changed in the envelope and correct business method can be called sooner based on the query parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

A status update would include the unique EnvelopeID (Which is a GUID) as well as the envelope status which is one of fixed number of values like "sent" "voided" "complete" etc.